# Open and close highslide with same button

Tags: highslide

Is there any way to use the same link or button to close an Higslide iframe as the one you open it with?

If you checkout the [highslide example](http://www.highslide.com/examples/iframe.html) and click on "Content in iframe" it opens up nicely. To close it you either click on esc or the Close (X) button in the highslide that just opend up.

What I want to achive is to close it by clicking on  the "Content in iframe"-link, the very same link that I open the highslide with.

On this example, you need to move the highslide to see the "Content in iframe",  since it opens up on top of that link. But I move the hislide with

```
targetX: 'my-target 0px',
targetY: 'my-target 24px',
```

So it looks like this

```
<div id="my-target">
<a href="test_include-short_highslide.htm"  
    target="_blank" 
    onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { 
    objectType: 'iframe', 
    anchor: 'top left',
    targetX: 'my-target 0px',
    targetY: 'my-target 24px',
    width: 350, 
    height: 250} )">
    Content in iframe
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onmousedown` to close the popup from the same link.

```
<div id="my-target">
<a href="test_include-short_highslide.htm"  
    target="_blank" 
    onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { 
    objectType: 'iframe', 
    anchor: 'top left',
    targetX: 'my-target 0px',
    targetY: 'my-target 24px',
    width: 350, 
    height: 250} )" 
    onmousedown="return hs.close(this)">
    Content in iframe
</a>
</div>
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xWLrU/